# Calculate liner integral by coordinates.

Tags: integration

Here is the problem:

Calculate liner integral by coordinates:
[image: problem]

How to solve this? or at least show me how to write the Integral expression please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integration has to be done along $y=x^2$. This give $x=\sqrt{y}$ as $x\ge0$. So, substitute that in the integral and put the appropriate limits of $y$, that is, from $y=1$ (point $A$) to $y=4$ (point $B$). The integral becomes:
$$\int_1^4\left(\sqrt{y}-\frac1y\right)dy$$